# Loading wide dataset via API into Data Extension in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap, dataextensions

We currently have a web application and it is populating in SFMC a very wide data extension (over 150 columns) with data from the website.

We are using the FuelSDk which is upserting the records into the DE using SOAP.

This works however after the number of records gets above 15 records we start getting huge deterioration of service and it can take over 5 minutes.

Is there another way of loading this data without using an import activity (REST method etc) - we do not want to use import as we have over 100 DE per month.

Comment: You probably need to ditch the SDK and code directly against the WSDL poasting SOAP directly with Asynchronous calls. The SDK's limited to synchronous calls which will leave your application waiting. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asynchronous_processing_syntax_guide.htm

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMcLeod - do you have any examples? We have looked everywhere but cannot actually find a successful example.

Comment: For the SOAP API, this is a useful starting point:

http://sforce.co/2hqO5fp

And this post has a good example of the raw SOAP envelope:

http://bit.ly/2kF2z9V

Another place to look in online documentation would be this page that gives some useful code samples in various languages to work with once you've created a reference to the WSDL in your project:

http://sforce.co/2gylnEM